# Can't Compile Hello World Program

Tags: c++

I recently decided to try my hand at C++, and right off the bat I don't know what I'm doing.
I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010.  Just like for Java in Eclipse I created a new project and make a new file in the source folder.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int() main 
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And I this is what I get when I try to build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Hello.cpp
1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.cpp(4): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.cpp(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\dylan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.cpp(5): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit:  Ah damn that was an incredibly stupid mistake.  Obviously I need to look more closely at the text.  Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: `int() main` should be `int main()`.

Comment: Why, WHY was your first reaction after deciding to speak a new language you had never used before "Let's ask on Stack Overflow", and not "Let's go and learn this language"?

Comment: Man... This is a **dumb** question. Excuse me, but it is. Seriously, **why couldn't you be bothered to at least read that beginners' tutorial carefully?**

Comment: No need to be rude, you guys. He's just a beginner with some confusion about C++ and our site. If you downvote, politely tell him in the comments why this question is poorly formatted for SO.

Answer (score 4):

```
int() main
```

should be

```
int main()
```

General form of function signatures is (simplified)

> [return type] [function name] **(** [parameter type] [parameter name] **,** ... **)**

or

> [return type] [function name] **( )**

if the function does not require arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I notice is that the parantheses should be after the main keyword, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error - line 4 should be `int main()`